# Can I put anything in a AD LDS?

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server-2016

I think I know what a AD DS is (Active directory Domain service). It register all users, computers, servers for an organisation. But what can I do with AD LDS? Can I store data for all the organisations cars?
An AD LDS is just some kind of database so I thought by making the right schema it would be possible to store various data about an organisations cars, for instance brand, registrations number and so on, or are there limitations for what can be done by LDS ?

Comment: Not unless your cars run the Windows OS

Comment: Why do you think that only things running Windows can be stored in an AD?

Comment: "AD LDS is one of two identity providers that are supported by Active Directory Federation Services (AD FS) for authentication purposes and to supply claims to federation-aware Web applications, the other being AD DS. AD LDS is also a supported store for authorization policy by Windows Authorization Manager (AzMan). In environments where AD DS exists, AD LDS can use AD DS for the authentication of Windows security principals."

Comment: "Active Directory Domain Services (AD DS) is the cornerstone of every Windows domain network. It stores information about members of the domain, including devices and users, verifies their credentials and defines their access rights. "

Comment: Cars are not members of a Windows domain ...

Comment: "Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services (AD LDS), formerly known as Active Directory Application Mode (ADAM), is a light-weight implementation of AD DS."

Comment: authorization plays an important role, but can you give me an example of something which can't be stored in an AD DS but in an AD LDS?

Comment: No. Read my previous comment. AD LDS **is an implementation** of AD DS.